# Javascript wont load if iframe is present

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am unable to get javascript to load in a page that contains an iframe.  I deleted the iframe and it loads just fine.

Here is the relevant html:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="Welcome.html" width=50% height=90% name="iframe"/>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
Fname = prompt("Please type in your first and Last name", " George Washington");
Fname = Fname + "";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iFrames are not defined like that

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="Welcome.html" width=50% height=90% name="iframe"/> No Frame Support </iframe>
```

Give that a go

Its implicitly closing the tag at the end, And the middle of an iframe is the no frame support

Answer (score 0):

Your JS should be inside the body. I believe you also need a separate closing tag for the iframe.